# How to use jquery's .html() method to set contents of div to another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

here i have some links `<a href>`s and these href's are linked to divs. when i click the link, the linked div contents should appear in another `div`.

for this i am trying to use jquery's `.html()` method.
first i am trying to get the id of the clicked div.and from that id, get the contents of that div and set the inner contents of div to dispfe `div`. but its not working....

how can i do this?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>InnerHtml</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        var $td = $(event.target.id);
        alert($td);
    });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

             <a href="#d1" id="f1">Head Light</a><br /> 
             <a href="#d2" id="f2">Hood</a> <br />
             <a href="#d3" id="f3">Wind-shield</a><br /> 
             <a href="#d4" id="f4">Rear wheels</a> <br />
             <a href="#d5" id="f5">Sun roof</a> <br />
             <a href="#d6" id="f6">Front wheels</a> <br />
             <a href="#d7" id="f7">Front hoop</a> <br />
             <a href="#d8" id="f8">Rear mirrors</a> <br />
             <a href="#d9" id="f9">Finishing</a> <br />


    <div id="d1" style="display:none;"> A headlamp is a lamp attached to the front of a     </div>

    <div id="d2" style="display:none;"> he hood bonnet is the hinged cover over the engine  </div>

    <div id="d3" style="display:none;"> The windshield or windscreen of an aircraft, car, bus, </div>

    <div id="d4" style="display:none;"> In automotive design, the automobile layout describes   </div>

    <div id="d5" style="display:none;"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing </div>

    <div id="d6" style="display:none;"> The term motorcar has formerly also been used </div>

    <div id="d7" style="display:none;"> The weight of a car influences fuel consumption </div>

    <div id="d8" style="display:none;"> Most cars are designed to carry multiple occupants</div>

    <div id="d9" style="display:none;"> Mary Ward became one of the first documented </div>

<br />



<div class="dispfe" style="width:40%;height:400px;border:solid black 1px;">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function(event) {
            $(".dispfe").html($($(this).attr('href')).html());
        });
    });
```

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/bTF6R/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        var href = $(event.target.id);
        $(".dispfe").html($(href).html());
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
alert(href);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `href="#d8` use `data-href="d8"` and with jQuery:

```
$('a[data-href]').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href'));
  $('#d1').html(target.html());
});
```